# Why Is $\operatorname{Ln}(z)$ The Inverse Of $e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\operatorname{Ln}(z)=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$$

so taking it as the power of $e$ we get

$$e^{\operatorname{Ln}(z)}=e^{\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)}=e^{\ln|z|}\cdot e^{i\operatorname{Arg}(z)}=|z|\cdot \operatorname{cis}(\operatorname{Arg}(z))$$

How do we arrive to $z$ from there?

Comment: $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$.

Comment: For complex $z$ we have $z=r \cdot e^{i \theta}$, where $r=|z|$. See [Complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA correct, it was fixed

Comment: What complex number has its length equal to $|z|$ and makes the same angle with the $x$-axis as $z?$

Comment: Because $$|z|\cdot\text{cis}(\text{Arg}(z))\equiv |z|e^{i\text{Arg}(z)}\equiv z.$$ $|z|$ is the magnitude of $z$ and $e^{i\text{Arg}(z)}$ gives the direction of $z$ of unit length (since $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$), so as a product they give you $z$ back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{Ln(z)}=e^{ln|z|+iArg(z)}=e^{ln|z|}e^{iArg(z)}=|z|cis(Arg(z))=^{(*)}z$

(*) - Any complex number $z=a+ib$ can be represented as $z=r*(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))$
where $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} , \theta=arctan(\frac b a)$.

This representation is called "Polar Representation", and can be derived by looking at the complex plane as a coordinate system where the vertical axis represents the $i$ component of $z$ and the horizonal axis represents the real component of z.

Answer (score 0):

$$|z|\text{ cis}\arg z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\text{ cis}\left(\arctan\frac yx\right).$$

Then from

$$\cos\theta=\frac1{\sqrt{\tan^2\theta+1}},\sin\theta=\frac{\tan\theta}{\sqrt{\tan^2\theta+1}}$$ we draw

$$\text{cis}\left(\arctan\frac yx\right)=\frac{1+i\dfrac yx}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{y^2}{x^2}}}$$

and finally

$$|z|\text{ cis}\arg z=x+iy.$$